# Does a global threading Lock need to be declared as global within a method in order to aquire it?

Tags: python, global-variables

When acquiring a globally instantiated lock inside a method, do we need to declare the lock as global with the `global` keyword?

If not, why not? Are we not modifying the lock by acquiring it?

I am imaging a case along the lines of:

```py
import threading
name_lock = threading.Lock()
name: str = ""
...

def modify_name(new_name: str):
    global name
    with name_lock:
        name = new_name

...
```

Comment: `global` only informs function that it has to use external/global variable when you will try to assign new value using `=` - like `name = new_name` - but it doesn't need this when you want to change some variable inside object - ie. `my_list.append(value)`. And `with name_lock` doesn't assign new value to variable `name_lock` but it only execute some methods inside object `name_lock` which change inner values.

Comment: @furas ah that totally makes sense! Feel free to make your comment an answer and I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables created outside functions/classes are automatically global variables.

We use `global` only inside function(s) to informs function that it has to use external/global variable when you will try to assign new value using `=` - like `name = new_name` - if you don't use `global` then it will create local variable `name`. But it doesn't need this when you want to change some value/variable inside object - ie. `my_list.append(value)`. And `with name_lock` doesn't assign new value to variable `name_lock` but it only executes some methods inside object `name_lock` which changes inner values.